# Where to find a minimalistic but fully compatible DLNA audio media renderer implementation or XML device description?

Tags: library, audio, c++, c, dlna

I'm working on an embedded Linux C/C++ project for capturing audio streams from various DLNA media senders and using the data for LED visualization effects.

I have looked at multiple UPNP and DLNA frameworks - libdlna, Intel's UPNP microstack, Platinum, gupnp. For the time being I have picked gupnp because all the other libraries seem to be abandoned, broken or too complex/messy or having inappropriate licensing.

I started with gupnp tutorials but they are too minimalistic - just a "hello world" bulb on/off service. But gupnp documentation mentions that it can build a service template from a device specification in XML format, if I had one.

So, where do I get a device specification that would describe all the DLNA mandatory audio streaming services (RenderingControl, ConnectionManager, AVTransport etc., if any) and their actions to generate gupnp code which would make my device discoverable as a DLNA media renderer from any other DLNA controller?

*If you know any other DLNA library (free for commercial use or MIT-like or at least LGPL licensed) or a DLNA renderer project which is beginner friendly, well documented and will help me achieve the same goal, I might accept it, too - I have not strictly decided about gupnp yet.*

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185), [code fragments](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. – so the tutorial part (second-to-last paragraph) is off-topic here.

Comment: @Izzy - I guess, that's a typical compromise of the stackexchange network. If I ask the same question on Stackoverflow, I get rejection for asking for 3rd party solutions or libraries because that's too close to software recommendations. If I don't mention libraries at all and only ask for the code fragments, I'd receive answers mentioning the same libraries I've already tried. So I have no idea, how to split the question in two - one for softwarerecs and another for stackoverflow without losing the context...

Comment: Well, I didn't say the entire question is OT here. It's just we don't recommend tutorials etc. here. Your last paragraph solves that perfectly IMHO, making "being well documented" a requirement.